# Why is the clip_grad_norm_ function used here?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am learning LSTM with PyTorch from someone's code. Here he uses the `clip_grad_norm_` function in the training process of a two layer LSTM. I want to know why he uses the `clip_grad_norm_` function here, so I can understand the whole code properly (he used it in second last line).

```
for x, y in get_batches(data, batch_size, seq_length):
    counter += 1
                            
    x = one_hot_encode(x, n_chars)
    inputs, targets = torch.from_numpy(x), torch.from_numpy(y)
            
    if(train_on_gpu):
        inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()

    h = tuple([each.data for each in h])                    
    net.zero_grad()
                            
    output, h = net(inputs, h)                
            
    loss = criterion(output, targets.view(batch_size*seq_length).long())
    loss.backward()

    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), clip)
    opt.step()
```

If you need more information about question then please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_.html) performs gradient clipping. It is used to mitigate the problem of [exploding gradients](https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/), which is of particular concern for recurrent networks (which LSTMs are a type of).

Further details can be found in the [original paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/pascanu13.pdf).